# JQuery Calculator for Different Conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hint: I'm not looking to everyone here for an 100% solution to my problem, but the right code guidance and I pick it up to implement for the rest.

The Web-Page for reference can be found [here](http://polarbear.brand-heart.co.za/newCalculator.html)

```
The Problem
If you click on the link, you see a section with input boxes, a Price of Phone box 
and B!-B4, T1 to T4 boxes..
The task is this, The System Admin are going to be able to input values into this boxes.

Price of Phone 700
B1 600 B2 500  B3 899 B4 900  **(these prices are fixed and would be disabled)**
```

So User 1:
    if User 1 wants the term for 12months
    so its going to be var A = {Price of Phone/12months}
    store this value

```
    if 12months is selected:
       var a= (Price of Phone/12months)
          {
            if B1:{
                        var b = $("#b1").val();
                    if 6months:{
                            do this 
                            var c = (b/6);
                        }else if 12months:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/12);
                        }else if 18monts:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/18);
                        }else{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/24);
                                }
                    }
            elseif B2:{
                        var b = $("#b2").val();
                    if 6months:{
                            do this 
                            var c = (b/6);
                        }else if 12months:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/12);
                        }else if 18monts:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/18);
                        }else{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/24);
                                }
                    }
            elseif B3:{
                        var b = $("#b3").val();
                    if 6months:{
                            do this 
                            var c = (b/6);
                        }else if 12months:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/12);
                        }else if 18monts:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/18);
                        }else{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/24);
                                }
                    }
            elseif B4:{
                        var b = $("#b3").val();
                    if 6months:{
                            do this 
                            var c = (b/6);
                        }else if 12months:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/12);
                        }else if 18monts:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/18);
                        }else{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/24);
                                }
                    }
          }
elseif 24months is selected:
       var a= (Price of Phone/24months)
          {
            if B1:{
                        var b = $("#b1").val();
                    if 6months:{
                            do this 
                            var c = (b/6);
                        }else if 12months:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/12);
                        }else if 18monts:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/18);
                        }else{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/24);
                                }
                    }
            elseif B2:{
                        var b = $("#b2").val();
                    if 6months:{
                            do this 
                            var c = (b/6);
                        }else if 12months:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/12);
                        }else if 18monts:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/18);
                        }else{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/24);
                                }
                    }
            elseif B3:{
                        var b = $("#b3").val();
                    if 6months:{
                            do this 
                            var c = (b/6);
                        }else if 12months:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/12);
                        }else if 18monts:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/18);
                        }else{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/24);
                                }
                    }
            elseif B4:{
                        var b = $("#b3").val();
                    if 6months:{
                            do this 
                            var c = (b/6);
                        }else if 12months:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/12);
                        }else if 18monts:{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/18);
                        }else{
                            do this
                             var c = (b/24);
                                }
                    }
          }
              function() {

        var total = (a) + (c) + (any other hidden charges)
        var monthly = total / 12;
        var weekly = total / 52;

        $('#total').val(total);
        $('#total12').val(monthly);
        $('#total52').val(weekly);

    }
```

Can I please get the Jquery code to solve this please, my current jquery code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/iiMHnQbS) you can improve on it from there.

Comment: are the B1/2/3/4 prices fixed to 600/500/899/900? Is the price of phone always 700? Is there more than one 'User'? Where is the 'c' variable coming from? You need to be clearer in your question.

Comment: @shennan, the prices are fixed and the phone price  would always be fixed too. Different Users would be using the system. and variable c could be hidden numbers to add..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly; you'd like to extrude the total 'value' of these variable user options.

What you'll need is a `function` that can do this calculation, that gets called each time you change an option.

Something like this:

```
function optionClicked () {

  var price = parseInt($('#phone').val()) || 700;
  var terms = [12, 11];
  var durations = [6, 12, 18, 24];
  var plans = [
    parseInt($('#bb1').val()) || 600,
    parseInt($('#bb2').val()) || 500,
    parseInt($('#bb3').val()) || 899,
    parseInt($('#bb4').val()) || 900
  ];

  var term = $('.selected-term').parent().index();
  var plan = $('.selected-cplan').parent().index();
  var duration = $('.selected-month').parent().index();

  var total = (price / terms[term]) + (plans[plan] / durations[duration])
  var monthly = total / 12;
  var weekly = total / 52;

  $('#total').val(total);
  $('#total12').val(monthly);
  $('#total52').val(weekly);

}
```

[Here's another pastebin](http://pastebin.com/Pz4TpbBH) with a usage example.

Comment: @SolomonOmokehinde It is working my end. Make sure you're calling the `optionClicked` method. You might want to just copy and paste the pastebin code verbatim if you're not familiar with how Javascript methods work.

Comment: @SolomonOmokehinde It's simply a case of getting the numbers you need from the inputs before performing the calculation. I have updated the answer/pastebin example to suit your needs.

Comment: @SolomonOmokehinde they are of the active buttons. Why don't you copy and paste the code in and actually see if it works?

Comment: @SolomonOmokehinde which div do you want a default value to go, and what default value is it that you want?

Comment: $('#total').val(Math.round(total).toFixed(2)); to display the var total value of selected button on page load. Thanks